# Solve $y'=\frac{x+y-2}{x-y}$ ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y'=\frac{x+y-2}{x-y}$$

$$\begin{vmatrix} 
  1    & 1\\ 
  1 & -1
\end{vmatrix}\neq0 $$

Substation: $x=u+\alpha$ , $y=v+\beta$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{du}$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
  1    & 1\\ 
  1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
  \alpha    \\ 
  \beta 
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 
  2    \\ 
  0 
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow \alpha=1\text{ , }\beta=1 $$

So:

$x=u+1$

$y=v+1$

$$y'=\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{u+1+v+1-2}{u+1-(v+1)}$$

$$\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{u+v}{u-v}$$

$$\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{u+v}{u-v}$$

$$\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{1+\frac{v}{u}}{1-\frac{v}{u}}$$

$z=\frac{v}{u}\Rightarrow v=uz$

$$\frac{dv}{du}=z+u\frac{dz}{du}=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$$

How should I continue?

Comment: this is a equation of Abel-type

Comment: A small drawing indicates that the graph of the solution (in $u$ and $v$) hits the lines through the origin in the $(u,v)$ coordinate system all under the same angle (45°). This is a fundamental property of the logarithmic spirals. So can try a parametrized representation of the logarithmic spirals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u\frac{dz}{du}=\frac{1+z}{1-z}-z=\frac{z^2+1}{1-z}$ thus
$$\frac{1-z}{1+z^2}dz=\frac{1}{u}du$$
or
$$\left(\frac{1}{1+z^2}-\frac{z}{1+z^2}\right)dz=\frac{1}{u}du$$
as a result
$$\tan^{-1}(z)-\frac12\ln(1+z^2)=C+\ln(u)$$